# WordPress API route unreachable

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, routes, wordpress-rest-api

When calling Axios put() method with my WordPress custom route I'm getting this error in console:

> PUT http://my-project.com/wp/wp-json/contact/v1/send 404 (Not Found)

Here's how I define my custom route in WP's `functions.php`:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'contact/v1', 'send', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'sendContactMail'
  ));
});
```

Here's the call in my app (Vue.js):

```
this.$axios.$put(`${this.baseUrl}/wp-json/contact/v1/send`, formData)
  .then((res) => {
    this.success = true
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    this.$toast.error(err.response)
  })
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You defined method POST but are using PUT

Comment: Thanks :) If you make an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `methods` section of the `register_rest_route` call, only the `POST` method is allowed, but your code is using `PUT`.

You can either change your axios call to `axios.post` or add the `PUT` method in your route definition.  To do that, change `methods`, which can be a string of comma-separated HTTP methods or an array of strings like:

```js
'methods' => 'POST,PUT',
```

OR

```js
'methods' => ['POST','PUT'],
```